# Iterating through table cells using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table containing a variable number of columns.  I wrote a function to iterate through each cell in each row to do the following:

1. Check for the presence of an input
2. Retrieve the value of the input
3. Append a pie chart to any cell where condition #1 evaluates to true

Here's my code:

```
function addPieCharts() {
var htmlPre = "<span class='inlinesparkline' values='";
var htmlPost = "'></span>"
var colors = ["red", "blue"];

$("#MarketsTable tr").each(function () {

    $('td').each(function () {
        var value = $(this).find(":input").val();
        var values = 100 - value + ', ' + value;

        if (value > 0) {
            $(this).append(htmlPre + values + htmlPost);
        }
     })

})

$('.inlinesparkline').sparkline('html', { type: 'pie', sliceColors: colors });
}
```

Steps 1-3 are basically working as described.  When this runs the pie charts are added to the correct cells displaying the correct values.  My problem is that I'm expecting just one pie chart per cell where there exists an input.  However, I have n pie charts per cell where n is equal to the number of columns in the table.  I suspect I'm using jQuery's each() method incorrectly.  Can someone tell me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you select `td` pass the context as tr(`this`) so that it will look for `td` only in the current `tr`. Try this.

```
$("#MarketsTable tr").each(function () {

    $('td', this).each(function () {
        var value = $(this).find(":input").val();
        var values = 100 - value + ', ' + value;

        if (value > 0) {
            $(this).append(htmlPre + values + htmlPost);
        }
     })

})
```

Comment: You can also use `$(this).find("td")`.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Yes that was it.  Working now.  Funny I was trying something similar but was off on the syntax (e.g. this + ' td').  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would modify you code:

- `#MarketsTable td:has(:input)`: this selector will find TD that has at leats one INPUT element inside
- no need to store your parts of html in variables IMO, just create the element when needed and append it to the TD

Here's the modified code:

```
function addPieCharts() {

    var colors = ["red", "blue"];

    // directly select the TD with an INPUT element inside
    $('#MarketsTable td:has(:input)').each(function() {

        var value = $(this).find(":input").val();

        if (value > 0) {

            // only make the values string if necessary, when value > 0
            var valStr = (100 - value).toString() + ', ' + value;

            // create your span tag and append it to 'this' (the TD in this case)
            $('<span class="inlinesparkline" values="' + valStr + '"></span>').appendTo(this);
        }

    });

    $('.inlinesparkline').sparkline('html', {
        type: 'pie',
        sliceColors: colors
    });
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/dVhfq/)**

Comment: I notice you eliminated the nested each().  Is there any performance advantage to doing it your way?

Comment: Heavy selectors are not efficient. .each() is less efficient than a for...loop. Honestly I don't know which way will be more efficient. It depends on how big your table is I guess.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 because I learned a few things from your answer.  I didn't know you could use a 'has' in a selector.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating every table element and nested cells to find out cell count for each table

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
   $("table").each(function (index) {
                
                var cellCount=0; 
                $("td",this).each(function (i){
                    cellCount++;
                })
                alert(cellCount);                
   })
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```