# jQuery adding css class

Tags: jquery

Good Day,

I have an HTML table that starts with one row of data. Each row has one dropdown and five input textboxes.  At the end of the row is an image that when clicked on will clone the last row and remove any data in the textboxes. The client wants the ability to create as many rows as needed.

I have some javascript/jquery that loops thorough every row and dynamically creates an object based on the name attribute for each select/input control.  Furthermore, I want validation for numeric fields (float or int).
That is working correctly. The problem is when the validation fails, I want a red border to be drawn around the input text.

Here is my code:

```js
$("input.submit").on('click', function(e) {

  var billingDetailRows = [];
  var detailRows = [];
  $('.miBillingDetails tbody tr').each(function(i, row) {

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132347/iterating-through-table-cells-using-jquery
    // The 'this' is necessary to ensure you only iterate through the row you're currently on
    var detailRow = {};
    var isNumeric = false;
    var dataType = '';
    $('td', this).each(function(e) {
      var domElement = $(this).find(':input');
      var attrName = '';
      if (typeof domElement != 'undefined') {
        attrName = domElement.attr('name');
        if (typeof attrName != 'undefined')
          console.log(attrName);
      }

      var dataType = domElement.attr('data-type');
      if (typeof dataType != 'undefined') {
        isNumeric = dataType === 'numeric';
        dataType = domElement.attr('data-format');
      }

      var value = $(this).find(':input').val();
      if (typeof value != 'undefined') {
        console.log(value === '' ? 'NONE' : value);
        var actualValue = value === '' ? '' : value;

        if (isNumeric && actualValue.length > 0) {
          if (!validateNumber(actualValue, dataType === 'int')) {
            $(domElement).css({
              "border-color": "#FF0000",
              "border-width": "1px",
              "border-style": "solid"
            });
            // $(domElement).addClass("errorBorder");
          }
        }

        detailRow[attrName] = actualValue;
      }
    });

    detailRows.push(detailRow);
  })
});
```

```css
.errorBorder {
  thin solid #FF0;
}
```

```html
<table class="miBillingDetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="RevenueType">
        <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
        <option value="CC">Credit Card</option>
        <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="BillingRate" data-type="numeric" data-format="float">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="Quantity" data-type="numeric" data-format="int">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="FlatRate" data-type="numeric" data-format="float">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="SequenceStart">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="SequenceEnd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="cloneWars" src="images/add2.jpg" alt="Add Tag" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem, I want to use addClass/removeClass.  But for whatever reason, this isn't working.  I have to set the css like it is to work.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA,

coson

Comment: have you also tried ``domElement.addClass("errorBorder");`` ?

Comment: are you sure that you have a valid css definition for that rule? doesn't seem so to me

Comment: @BettySt he has that commented out, I believe he's tried that

Comment: @godmode no he has commented out ``$(domElement)`` .. I wrote it without ``$()``

Comment: @BettySt, my mistake sorry about that

Comment: @BettySt, I tried that too, but no go:(

Comment: do you have any error? did you inspect the element and are you sure that the element doesn't have the class ``errorBorder``?

Comment: @BettySt - I inspected the element and checked the Console to ensure that there was no error.

Comment: It works when you open up the console on this stackoverflow page, and then do this: ``var domElement = $('body').find(':input'); domElement.addClass("errorBorder");``

Comment: @BettySt, I tried what you just did and it works on this page, but not sure why it's not working on my page.

Comment: Your CSS is not valid. You're missing the style keyword, e.g. ``border: thin solid #FF0`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Answer (score 1):

may or may not solve your issue, but domElement is already a jquery object so replace this

```
$(domElement).addClass("errorBorder");
```

with this

```
domElement.addClass("errorBorder");
```

Comment: Calling `$()` with jQuery object will just return a copy of the jQuery object. It will work, it's just not as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my answer was.  My CSS was not properly defined:

```
<style type="text/css">
    input { width: 125px; }
    .center { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
    margin:0 auto;   /* BAD FORMAT */
    .errorBorder {
        border: thin solid #F00;
    }
</style>
```

So while .errorBorder is a valid CSS entry, the margin:0 auto; wasn't.  So even though I could use addClass to add the style, it never rendered properly because of the "margin:0 auto".  After I removed this, everything worked the way I expected it to.  Didn't realize I pasted it there when I thought I removed it.